# How can I overlay backgroung on the Skybox in the Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to overlay mountain landscape on the Skybox (the background) but can't find the way ;(

I have two file types that have mountain image and they are .mat and Sprite.

[I add c# script in the prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZuWO.png)

```
internal class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TerrainGenerator Instance;
    public Material islandMaterial;

    public void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        if (islandMaterial != null)
        {
            SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = new SpriteRenderer();
            spriteRenderer.material = islandMaterial;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote that but it didn't appear, I can see just sky.

Thanks for reading my problem, I'm waiting you guys help!!

Do I need to use Inspector setting? I also tried this way, but also didn't work.

[Sprite Renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXmKN.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of component object yourself, it's not attached to any `GameObject`, so Unity has no way to do anything with it. Instead of manual calling to constructor, you need to call [`GameObject.AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) in order for Unity to register this component into the rest of the engine

Comment: Oh I miss the basic one. Thanks a lot, Alexey!